# Whenever another user logs on to a Windows 8.1 multi monitor machine, my Window positions are reversed when I log back in

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors

I’m the main user on a workstation running Windows 8.1 Update, using an AMD Radeon HD6950 GPU and two identical monitors in landscape mode. Another user occasionally uses the machine. I lock the machine whenever I’m away from it, and they log in as per usual, logging out when they are finished.

Frustratingly every time this happens, when I log back in, my window positions are changed from where they were prior to the other user logging in. Anything that was on the left monitor will now be on the right monitor, although the relative positions within the monitor are preserved. For instance, a window locked to the right hand side of the right monitor will be locked to the right hand side of the left monitor.

To be clear, I've checked the display settings under both users and they are identical as far as I can tell. In both cases, the display that Windows labels "1" is the same physical monitor, is on the left of the second monitor both physically and virtually, and both displays are oriented in landscape mode with the same resolution.

What is going on? Any ideas how I can stop it from happening? I’m finding it quite annoying.

Comment: Consider switching your monitors over to the way it works for your colleague and you might find that they stay aligned this way. The computer may consider the other way to be the natural order.

Comment: Just to be clear, there appears to be nothing different in our display configs. I'll edit the question

Comment: I am interpreting that the '1' is following a different physical monitor in the two settings. Is this right? This happened to me when a monitor failed - the '1' and '2' changed physical monitor attachment.

Comment: No, unfortunately - I wasn't clear. For both users, the monitor labelled by Windows as "1" is the same physical monitor, as well as being in the same relative position, orientation and also resolution. As far as I can tell, the setups are identical in every way.

Comment: My guess would be that windows is toggling to single display when user-switching then toggling back. These changes always make a mess of window positions. Might just have to live with it.